# Mercurial [subpaths] containing absolute path is appended to main repo's default path when pushing

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

Running Mercurial 2.0.2 on Windows:

In my .hgrc:

```
[subpaths]
MYREPOS/(.*) = https://server/repos/\1
```

And in my .hgsub:

```
subrepo/lib = MYREPOS/lib
```

When I do a push, the push path of the sub repo is the concatenation of it's path to the main repo, rather than an absolute path - the output is:

```
pushing to https://server/repos/main 
pushing subrepo subrepo\lib to https://server/repos/main/http%3A//server/repos/lib
```

I would have expected:

```
pushing to https://server/repos/main
pushing subrepo subrepo\lib to https://server/repos/lib
```

Is it because the 'absoluteness or relativeness' of the sub repo path is determined by right hand path in .hgsub and not the value it is mapped to? For example, MYREPOS/lib is relative, and therefore the mapped path will be treated as relative, whether it is or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subrepository logic was changed [between 1.9 and 2.0](http://selenic.com/hg/rev/91dc8878f888). The procedure is now:

1. if the path in `.hgsub` is relative, then join it with the main repository path
2. apply remapping rules to this final path

Before this change, we would:

1. apply remapping rules to the path from `.hgsub`
2. if the remapped path is relative, then join it with the main repository path

So you're right that `MYREPOS/lib` is seen as a relative path in the first step. The full path for the subrepository is therefore

```
https://server/repos/main/MYREPOS/lib
```

and your remapping pattern still triggers. This explains why you see `http://...` in the middle of the push URL. However, there is a **fallback** that will revert to the old behavior. If your pattern is

```
^MYREPOS/(.*) = https://server/repos/\1
```

then it wont match anything in the new step 2 — it will only remap `MYREPOS` at the beginning of the path. We notice this and use the old algorithm!